# Linear Programs using R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, lpsolve

How can we solve a linear program using R? I want to solve the following example:

```
min -a -2b +4c

Constraints
a + b + s1 = 5
a + 3c -s2 = 10
2b - 3c = 20

a >= 0, b >= 0, c >= 0, s1 >= 0, s2 >= 0
```

The equations might not make total sense. I just need to know the syntax of writing these equations in R.
I might write something like this for the above equations

```
require(lpSolve)

R.obj <- c(-1,-2,4)

R.con <- matrix(c(1,1,1,1,3,-1,2,-3),nrow=3,byrow=TRUE)

R.dir <- c("=","=","=")

R.rhs <- c(5,10,20)

lp("min",R.obj,R.con,R.dir,R.rhs)
```

Would this be correct? In the documentation, the matrix is always `M*M`, what if the matrix is `M*N` where `N != M`?

Comment: If you're just looking to learn the syntax, the package's documentation might be a good starting point: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lpSolve/lpSolve.pdf

Comment: I am not understanding how to create the constraints when I add slack, surplus variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constraint matrix has 3 rows and 5 columns, but you've only provided the 8 non-zero values when building your constraint matrix. Further, you have 5 variables, so `R.obj` needs 5 values:

```
require(lpSolve)
R.obj <- c(-1, -2, 4, 0, 0)
R.con <- matrix(c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, -3, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0), nrow=3)
R.dir <- c("=", "=", "=")
R.rhs <- c(5, 10, 20)
lp("min", R.obj, R.con, R.dir, R.rhs)
# Error: no feasible solution found
```

A bit of math shows that this LP is indeed infeasible. This LP is equivalent to `-a - b >= -5`, `a + 3c >= 10`, `b = 10 + 1.5c`. You can substitute the last equation into the first to yield `-a - 1.5c >= 5` and `a + 3c >= 10`, and adding yields `c >= 10`. By your third equation, `b >= 25`, which means the first equation can never hold due to the non-negativity of `a` and `s1`.

Comment: can you tell me what is Error Status : 3 in R mean?

Comment: @kartik sorry, where are you seeing this error status?